# Error on result of linq expression (and anounymous type)

Tags: c#, linq, type-conversion

I have a linq query in my class.  When I try to return one or another result the compiler throw a conversion type error related a "Anonymous Type" and I found no solution for it.

This is my code:

```
public static string VerificaExame(string desc)
{
    var model = new ExameContext();
    var res = model.DbExame.Where(exame => exame.Descricao.Trim() == desc.Trim()).Select(exame => new { Id = exame.Id, Codigo = exame.Codigo });
    if (res == null)
        res = model.DbExame.Where(exame => exame.Codigo.Trim() == desc.Trim()).Select(exame => new { Id = exame.Id, Descricao = exame.Descricao });
    var ret = res.FirstOrDefault();
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ret);
}
```

And the error message:

> Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

This error is referent to:

```
res = model.DbExame.Where(exame => exame.Codigo.Trim() == desc.Trim()).Select(exame => new { Id = exame.Id, Descricao = exame.Descricao });
```

Comment: Isn't your res variable returning each time a different object??

Comment: Really, the members of res previous defined not can be converted or are read only.

Answer (score 1):

Use a different variable (do not use `res`)

```
var res = model.DbExame.Where(exame => exame.Descricao.Trim() == desc.Trim()).Select(exame => new { Id = exame.Id, Codigo = exame.Codigo });
//^ Now res is of a specific type (ie: IEnumerable<Anonymous1>)
if (res == null)
    var res2 = model.DbExame.Where(exame => exame.Codigo.Trim() == desc.Trim()).Select(exame => new { Id = exame.Id, Descricao = exame.Descricao });
    //^ you cant affect res2 to res because they are of different type
```

---

`if (res == null)` res will never be null, may be you want `if (!res.Any())` to see if `res` has items.

---

This is what you should do:

```
public static string VerificaExame(string desc)
{
    var model = new ExameContext();
    object res = (object)model.DbExame.Where(exame => exame.Descricao.Trim() == desc.Trim())
                                .Select(exame => new { Id = exame.Id, Codigo = exame.Codigo })
                                .FirstOrDefault()
        ??
        (object)model.DbExame.Where(exame => exame.Codigo.Trim() == desc.Trim())
                        .Select(exame => new { Id = exame.Id, Descricao = exame.Descricao })
                        .FirstOrDefault();

    if (res != null)
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res);
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject("");//Or throw an exception
}
```

Comment: Yes, I even thought about it, but I thought it might be another way ...
Thank you @Ahmed-KRAIEM

Comment: Oh nooooo :(
    Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'AnonymousType#1' and 'AnonymousType#2'

Comment: Thans for all. I solve this problem with sugestion to use 2 variables. ;)

Comment: Yeah sorry, edited (added cast to `object`). Consider accepting the answer.